# Apache Tomcat Server (in Linux Machine) Locale & Unicode Characters Replaced with '?'

Tags: java, tomcat, unicode, production-environment

I have a java spring MVC application that accept requests from client and send back Json data to Client. The Json data contains Unicode charachters .The application works fine on my development machine (Linux mint, Apache Tomcat) but when i deploy the generated war file on other server (Ubuntu, Same Apache Tomcat Version), All Persian Unicode characters in responses body have been replaced with '?'

Here is a sample of response body that i got from Apache Tomcat in browser

```
> {     "id": 5186,     "title": "magh",    "respubdate": "2015-10-05",
>   "acceptdate": "2015-09-28",     "author": "??? ?????",
>   "subject_category_id": 109,     "subject_category_name": "???? ????",
>   "comment": null,    "event_title": "????? ???????? ? ????? ??????",
>   "orgunit_child_name": "???? ?",     "orgunit_parent_name": "????????
> ?????? ??????? ? ????????" }
```

I also set

```
<Connector port="8080" 
 URIEncoding="UTF-8"
/>
```

in Server.xml of Apache Tomcat, but nothing changed.

Apache Tomcat Version: 7.0.6

Comment: Have you encoded the file in unicode when saving it? This usually occurs when the physical file isn't saved with the appropriate encoding. Most text editors and IDEs will allow you to 'save with encoding'.

Comment: Can you guive us the whole chain which builds this JSON strng ? I guess that you miss to provide the encoding somewhere in the chain in your code.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele this is not ablout files, Client send requests and JSONs return back by server

Comment: @mvera I encoded the Json and it works on development machine,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. when i ran the

```
locale -a
```

on both development and production machines. I saw differences between the installed locals on machine. I install the missed locale (language) packages on production machine and every thing seems good ;)